# Cross domain Ajax call In Blackberry Webworks Error Bad Request

Tags: jquery, blackberry-webworks, ripple

I'm very new to blackberry webworks. When I'm writing a jQuery ajax request to a Asp.net webservice which accepts two value. It returns Error Bad request. I'm using ripple for Chrome plugin for testing. The code is

```
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://xyz.in/webservice.asmx/backup_p",
    data: "{ 'id': '1', 'data': '4' }",

    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert('sucess !!!');
        alert(msg.d);


    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('hello');

        alert(jqXHR + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I tried many methods but without any solution. It is something to do with ripple?

Answer (score 1):

Your json is invalid, it should be `{ "id": "1", "data": "4" }`, notice how the key and string quotes are `"` instead of `'`.
Also instead of building ajax by hand use JSON.stringify. e.g.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 'id': '1', 'data': '4' }),
```

Comment: To add on to Musa's answer,you should use http://jsonlint.com/ to check if your JSON is valid or not.Most of the time the problem with JSON is simply malformed JSON strings.

Comment: @Musa 

Now Getting Response Header

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 10 Jun 2013 04:07:01 GMT
Content-Length: 5231

kindly help

Comment: A 404 means your url is wrong, find out what is the correct url and use that.

Comment: The url is http://andi.alcance.in/webservice.asmx and the method is backup_p. Kindly check it.

Comment: @sambit.albus I don't think that service supports json only soap.

Comment: @Musa go to same URL now and click on any of the method and enter values in the textbox it will return a JSON value. Check it yourself.

Comment: @sambit.albus nope, now its just plain xml